# Некорректное отображение страницы в предпросмотре, Mozilla, CSS

Tags: css, firefox

Как с помощью стилей исправить отображение документа в предпросмотре печати в Mozilla? Документ не умещается на страницу.

Пытался прикрутить что то вроде этого, но не помогает:

```
  @-moz-document url-prefix()
          {
          @media print
          {
            .page
          {
          text-align: left;
          width: 700px;
          height: 900px;

          }
          }
```

[Здесь предосмотр, как выглядит сейчас](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z09QK.png)

[Как выглядит этот же документ в Хроме](http://prntscr.com/gthg5y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Убираем лишние поля при печати:

```
@media print { 
    @page {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Тут дело скорее всего не в паддингах. Их я убрал, как вы предложили,  но проблема осталась : http://prntscr.com/gthhly

Проблема в том, что он не умещается на странице, причем пытаюсь изменить по высоте, но он никак не реагирует. 
Добавил в описание скрин, как выглядит в хроме